# Clean architecture and state pattern

Tags: design-patterns, clean-architecture

I am working in an GUI application that would work as follows:

It will retrieve and save data from any of the following sources:

- A "Cloud Library": This library would get and save data to a cloud.
- JSON file: Some initial data are gotten from a large JSON file.
- Text file: Data retrieved from "cloud library" can be saved to a text file so that the application can be load data from it as well.

When the application starts it would ask for the JSON file to load the initial data. Once the JSON is loaded, the data of it would be shown in main window in a widget like a grid.

The application will have 3 states:

- **Offline**: Initial and default state. In this, the data displayed in GUI are disabled to be modified.
- **Cache**: Data displayed in GUI are able to be modified and to be saved only to
  local text files at request (i.e. when user clicks on "save" button).
- **Online**: Data displayed in GUI are able to be modified and they are saved to the cloud automatically, through the "Cloud library", once a change occurs. Optionally user can save the modifications to local files (i.e. when user clicks on "save" button).

The application would change to states as follows:

1. When application starts in "offline" state, and it behaves as follows:

   - After loading data from given JSON file, data is displayed in main window and disabled to modify them.
   - The name of the JSON file loaded is shown in status bar.
   - Entry "Show online data" from menu bar is disabled.
   - Entry "Real time graphic" is disabled.
   - Entry "Save data" is disabled.
2. If a text file is loaded with data previously saved, application changes to "Cache" status and:

   - The name of the JSON file loaded is shown in status bar.
   - Entry "Show online data" from menu bar is enabled.
   - Entry "Real time graphic" is disabled.
   - Entry "Save data" is enabled.
3. There is an entry called "Get online" in menu entry, when is pressed the application is connected to "Cloud library" and data is retrieved from cloud. It reaches to "Online" state:

   - Label "Online" instead of JSON file name is shown in status bar.
   - Entry "Show online data" from menu bar is enabled.
   - Entry "Real time graphic" is enabled.
   - Entry "Save data" is enable.
   - Data modified in the main grid is automatically updated in the cloud.
4. When "Get offline" in menu entry is pressed application goes again to "Cache" state.

I am implementing **Clean Achitecture** plus MVP to isolate GUI from bussines rules. Also to handle the states I plan to use **State Pattern** and here is where comes my question:

- As I would use MVP and it seems the states listed above affects only to GUI elements, the state pattern would only apply to "Presenter(s)" object(s)?

Comment: This would be a better question if it included more detail about your specific application and its unique requirements.  As it is currently written, it seems as if you're using these patterns just for the sake of using them.  That's not a good enough reason to use them.

Comment: Done, I have added details.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "Yes."  Logic for enabling and disabling controls is kept in the Presenter.  If you need more flexibility, you can use a Supervising Controller.  The Supervising Controller serves as your implementation of the State Pattern.   See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/mvp-model-view-presenter-%E2%80%93-supervising-controller/